# What R_FLOAT32 stand for in PixelFormat enum?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm especially wondering about the **R_**.

```
public: enum PixelFormat
{
    UNKNOWN_PIXEL_FORMAT = 0,
    L_INT8,
    L_INT16,
    RGB_INT8,
    RGBA_INT8,
    BGRA_INT8,
    RGB_INT16,
    RGB_INT32,
    BGR_INT8,
    BGR_INT16,
    BGR_INT32,
    R_FLOAT16,
    RGB_FLOAT16,
    R_FLOAT32, // <- This one
    RGB_FLOAT32,
    BAYER_RGGB8,
    BAYER_RGGR8,
    BAYER_GBRG8,
    BAYER_GRBG8,
    PIXEL_FORMAT_COUNT
};
```

Source: [Image.hh on gazebo Bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/b54961341ffb938a9f99c9976aed50a771c95216/gazebo/common/Image.hh?at=default#Image.hh-58)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9184/what-r_float32-stand-for-in-pixelformat-enum-?/) by [Hugo Start](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1328/hugo-start/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`R_FLOAT32` has one 32bit float value stored in the red channel.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0